# Как правильно отсортировать строку в алфавитном порядке?

Tags: javascript

```
// Создать функцию, которая упорядочит буквы в строке "екважбигёзд" в алфавитном порядке и возвратит строку в обратном порядке ("кизжёедгвба").

string = "екважбигёзд";

function sortAndReverse(string) {
  return string.split('').sort().reverse().join('');
}

console.log(sortAndReverse(string));
```

Получаю вывод: ёкизжедгвба
А нужен: кизжёедгвба

Я так понимаю нужно использовать LocaleCompare? Исправьте мой код пожалуйста, чтобы он работал верно

Comment: так передайте в sort колбэк с этим вашим localeCompare

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
const string = "екважбигёзд"
const collator =  new Intl.Collator('ru')

function sortAndReverse(string) {
  return string.split('').sort((a,b)=>collator.compare(a,b)).reverse().join('')
}

console.log(sortAndReverse(string))
```

UPD: Исходя из комментариев @Qwertiy @wololo @teran немного модифицируем и убираем лишний `revers`

```js
const string = "екважбигёзд"
const compare = (new Intl.Collator('ru')).compare

function sortAndReverse(string, reverse = false) {
  return string.split('')
    .sort((a, b) => ((reverse ? -1 : 1) * compare(a, b)))
    .join('')
}

console.log(sortAndReverse(string))
console.log(sortAndReverse(string, true))
```

Comment: Можно вместо `sort((a,b)=>collator.compare(a,b))` писать просто `sort(collator.compare)`

Comment: @wololo Действительно :(, это я лишнего сморозил - перекинув аргументы, когда с ними ничего не делаешь

Comment: @wololo, а если подумать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, что не так?

Comment: @wololo, `this` не так.

Comment: @wololo, хм.. я неправ. Оно само bind'ится, так что можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy на удивление работает без привязки this, по крайне мере в консоли браузера. Но выглядит как-то пугающе. Сам не могу понять почему :(

Comment: `collator.compare` — это геттер, возвращающий функцию.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, там геттер, который при чтении пишет в инстанс функцию: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jScHu.png. Причём до вызова геттера её там нет: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3tw0.png.

Comment: зато в первом варианте можно было сделать compare(b,a) или с минусом и избавиться от reverse

Comment: @teran даже использовать эту возможность и добавить параметр реверса